# Length of String vs. # of keys in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, string-length

So I was in an interview today and my interviewer and I weren't sure which is more efficient: given a long string of characters which is faster 'len(str)' or 'len(freqDict)' where freqDict is a dictionary with the character as the key and the frequency of the character in the string as the value?

Comment: What happened when you timed it yourself?

Comment: Are you asking about *python* strings or strings as a general data type?

Comment: @Bakuriu was a python example but is it generally true?

Comment: "len(freqDict)" - is that really the operation you're interested in? These seem like very strange operations to worry about the efficiency of, as both of them are constant-time and extremely short.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot As I answered *in python* `len(string)` is a O(1) operation, however in other languages strings are either null-terminated arrays (so you have to scan all the characters to compute the length), or linked lists (were you have to do the same thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "strings" and frequency dictionary:

If you are mentioning python data types `str` and `dict`:

Strings keep track of their length in a field of their C structure, which means `len(str)` is O(1), aka constant time (and with a very small constant).

With a frequency table you have to sum the counts, which is O(k) where `k` is the number of *distinct* letters in the string (assuming constant time integer operations, which isn't strictly true). Since the number of characters is bounded O(k) = O(1), so, *asymptotically*, they take the same time, but the difference in constants is pretty big: `len(str)` will always be faster. (also, if you consider unicode characters `k` can be in the order of millions, so it can be 10^6 times slower to use the frequency table).

If you mean "strings" in general then counting the character in a string takes O(n) time, while summing the counts in a frequency table is, as already stated, O(k) which is O(1) assuming a bounded number of characters. However this doesn't take into account the time to create the frequency table.

---

I'm assuming constant time operations on integers since this makes sense for real world usage. However, even with unbounded integers, the time taken to sum `k` integers would be less than O(n). In fact it should be about O(log(n)) because the operations has to compute the `log(n)` bits of the representation of `n` which is the length of the string.

(with the assumption of a bounded number of characters, otherwise you could have strings with length `n` and consisting of `n` distinct character for each `n`...)

---

Here I'm assuming that the problem you wanted to solve is to compute the length of the string by either counting the single characters or summing some counts.
However if you really meant `len(a_string)` vs `len(a_dict)` the answer is quite simpler: they both take the same O(1) time since both `str` and `dict` store a field with their length.

Comment: Why are you talking about summing the counts when the question is asking about `len(freqDict)`? It also says "# of keys" in the title, which isn't what summing the values does at all.

Comment: @user2357112 Because otherwise the question doesn't make sense... I assume the  problem is computing the *string's legth*. And he's asking whether is faster to simply count the characters by hand, or sum the counts someone already took.

Comment: @user2357112 Also, if he really meant `len(freqDict)` the answer is trivial: about the same time since both types store their length and the code to retrieve it should be identical.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make much sense, but that doesn't mean you should reinterpret it as a different question and answer that question without any mention of the reinterpretation.

Comment: @user2357112 I believe the correct interpretation is quite clear: why otherwise would he mention that `freqDict` contains exactly that information?

Comment: @user2357112 I didnt know both were implemented with a length field

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot *All* python built-in collections do that. In general it doesn't cost much to keep track of the length, so they do it. AFAIK in python `len(something)` is *expected* to be O(1) by users.

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot If you want to look at the implementation, you can see the python sources online [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/49dfe2630ae3/).  built-ins are under the `Objects` directory, `Modules` contains built-in modules written in C while `Lib` contains the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

For large length strings, the dictionary will be faster. Since there are only 26 letters in the english alphabet, there may be a maximum of 26 keys. Then you simply sum the values in the dictionary. A `len` operation forces you to walk the entire list (or string) in this case.

Using length

```
>>> s = 'halloween'
>>> len(s)                # O(N)
9
```

Using `dict`

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'e': 2, 'h': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'w': 1}
>>> sum(d.values())     # O(N) but capped at N = 26
9
```

Comment: Good point though the question was based on unicode characters so it wouldnt be 26 but youre point is right thanks didn't think of it this way

Comment: does python store the length of strings?  That is is len(s) O(1) because of the implementation?

Comment: @SamHartman I'm not sure, it depends on the implementation of the class, they may maintain the length of the string with the class. I guess my point is that at some time (at least once) you must walk the string to find its length. Though that notion stands for having to create the initial dictionary, but from OP's question I figured they were given the dictionary at the start of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but they're also given the string.  So, if str (the built in string class) stores the length, len will always be faster.

Comment: Why are you doing `sum(d.values())` when the question asks about its `len`?

Comment: @user2357112 If the dictionary stores the number of times each letter appears, summing the counts is indeed finding the length of the string, is that not clear?

Comment: But the question doesn't ask about finding the length of the string from the frequency dict. It says "len(freqDict)" and "# of keys".

Comment: Also, `len` is constant time for strings, dicts, and just about any other `len`-supporting type you'll encounter in Python.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [table](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) `list` `len` have O(1) complexity (it is precomputed). String also have precomputed lenght. So string len should be faster.

`len` method for most builtins objects in python implemented with [Py_SIZE](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Include/object.h#L116) macro.
Python strings are using [PyString_GET_SIZE](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Include/stringobject.h#L92) in C API for len, with is just alias for [Py_SIZE](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Include/object.h#L116).